# Excel - Pulling multiple values from same cell

Tags: excel, pivot

please see below data. How can i clean and pivot this data, I have about 40+ tags, and hundreds of pages. The end result is that I need to calculate the sum of views for each tag.

[image: excel]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMIF (or SUMIFS) with a wild-card criteria:
Assume defined names:
Data: Page is column A, Content_tags B, Page_Views C
Result: Content_Tag is Col A, Formula is in Col B

```
=SUMIF(Content_Tags,"*" & Content-tag & "*", Page_Views)
```